# how can i replace previous-text to font-awsome cheat sheet code in uib-pagination

Tags: css, pagination

iam trying to replace the uib-pagination previous-text and next-text to font-awesome cheat sheet or with a font awesome icon i tried like below but icons are not showing and then i tried to put the code but then it is taking as a string, how can i solve this, please solve my question

```
<div uib-pagination total-items="100" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" boundary-link-numbers="false" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" previous-text="&#xf060;" next-text="&#xf051;"></div>
```

[image]

this how iam getting , please solve my problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I may be wrong, but your code doesn't include any fa?

Comment: in my code i used font-awsome cheat sheet code ie., &#xf051; and &#xf060; those can act like fa fa arrow-right and left in font-awesome icons @Aer0